# Finding the homomorphisms $S_3 \to \Bbb Z / 6 \Bbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I have to find explicitly (i.e. as operated on the element of the domain) the homomorphisms (of groups) from the symmetric group $S_3$ to $\Bbb Z / 6 \Bbb Z$.

Do I study the possible kernels of the homomorphisms?

Comment: Yes, that's a viable idea. Enumerate all normal subgroups $N$ (there aren't many after all) and check if you can find $S_3/N$ as a subgroup (possibly in several ways?) of $\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm sorry for barging in on this thread but this question somehow caught my interest... would you mind elaborating a bit on how to count the number of homomorphisms from a group $G$ into a group $H$? What do you do once you found the normal subgroups of $G$? Is there a bijective correspondence between normal subgroups and homomorphisms? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Since $\Bbb Z / 6 \Bbb Z$ is abelian, we must have for any homomorphism $\phi: S_3 \to \Bbb Z / 6 \Bbb Z$ that (for all $a, b \in S_3$) $$\phi(a b a^{-1} b^{-1}) = \phi (a) + \phi(b) - \phi(a) - \phi(b) = 0.$$ Thus, $\ker \phi$ contains the (normal) commutator subgroup $[S_3, S_3]$ of $S_3$, and hence $\phi$ descends to a homomorphism $S_3 / [S_3, S_3] \to \Bbb Z / 6 \Bbb Z$. (This applies to all group homomorphisms $G \to H$ with $H$ abelian, in fact.) Can you identify what $[S_3, S_3]$ is?

Comment: The possible ker $\phi$ are ${id},S_3,A_3$?

Comment: $\ker \phi = \{\id\}$ is not possible, as $\{id\} \not\supseteq [S_3, S_3] = A_3$. (Indeed, if we had $\ker \phi = \{id\}$, $\phi$ would be an isomorphism onto its image, but $S_3$ is nonabelian and its image is abelian, a contradiction.)

Comment: if $ker(\phi)$=$S_3$ it's the homomorphism null but if $ker(\phi)$=$A_3$?

Comment: If $\ker \phi = A_3$, then (since $A_3$ normal), $\phi$ descends to a homomorphism $\bar{\phi}: S_3 / A_3 \to \Bbb Z / 6 \Bbb Z$. But $S_3 / A_3 \cong \Bbb Z_2$, so it is generated by its nonzero element. Thus, $\bar \phi$ (and hence $\phi$) is determined by $\bar \phi(1)$.